# Spatio-temporal visualisation with google maps

Tags: google-maps, visualization

I have **Call Detailed Records(CDR)** data which in its raw form has *timestamp*, *latitude* and *longitude*. I have summarized this data to show where a user was on a particular day. What I have now are three fields: Begin(Date),End(Date) and Lat/Lon. Worth noting is that intervals are irregular and Lat/Lon can repeat. My objective is to have a visualization/animation with the following capabilities. *Adjustable speed* when viewing time so that I can see when a user returns to the same place. It should look [something like this](http://googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.jp/2012/06/powerful-data-visualization-with.html) or [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rrVT7Tp4yEg). I have searched endlessly and cant seem to find pointers to resources for use in Google maps or similar platforms. Now I have a kml file for each user but when I view it in Google Earth, the effects are not what I'm looking for. Problems include speed,its too fast and for some reason I cant control the start date of the animation. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

CanvasLayer.js Library is what you have to integrate with your app code in order to get the sort of animated data on your Map. This library integrates Google Maps and Web GL behind the scenes and you just have to basic code for initialization and add path of your text/kml file, Rest of the things are automated.

Please follow [this](http://googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.com/2014/10/mixing-maps-and-webgl-to-visualize-huge.html) link to know about the code implementation and also some sample examples.

Hope this would Help!!

Comment: Thank you. I will have a look and give it a go.

Comment: You can accept the answer if you found it useful, so that others can refer too :)

Comment: I had a look at CanvasLayer.js Library but I still haven't got it to work. Partly its because I'm not so familiar with java script. But also because the examples which are on CanvasLayer.js documentation [link] (https://github.com/brendankenny/CanvasLayer) aren't close to what I'm trying to do. As a result I have decided to do some further reading on this as they don't seem to be a shortcut to get what I want.